# PHP - Counter issue using flock function

Tags: php, counter, flock

I am trying to block a file using the flock() function to avoid an overwrite error but the counter often resets (probably for a reading issue).

numeri.txt (counter)

```
4895|533753
```

frame.php (PHP file)

```
$filename="numeri.txt";
$contents=file_get_contents($filename);
if(($fp=@fopen($filename,'w'))!==false)
{
    if(flock($fp,LOCK_EX))
    {
        $contents=explode("|",$contents);
        $clicks=$contents[0];
        $impressions=$contents[1]+1;
        fwrite($fp,$clicks."|".$impressions);
        flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Sometimes the counter returns "|1" instead of "4895|533754".

How can I fix it?

Comment: May be you run the script frame.php twice with small delay?

Comment: It's a counter, the script runs more then 60 times in a minute. I used the flock function to avoid issues but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two threads will execute your code almost simultaneusly with the small delay, the 1st thread will open file for write and erase it contents before locking.

The 2nd thread will read the empty file contents, wait for lock release, and then overwrite the correct data.

The solution is to open file not in "w", but in "a" or "c" mode and then use fwrite, fseek and ftruncate.

Comment: I did it before your answer and now it works fine. But why should I use fseek?

Comment: It is not necessary in your case, it is just the common case remark.